# How to add extra row to tableview with textfield text "Amount" in swift

Tags: ios, swift, count, uitextfield, tableview

This struct in HomeVC:

```
struct JsonData{

var name: String = ""
var categoryname: String = ""
var customerdetails: [cDetails] = [cDetails]()

init(name: String, categoryname: String, customerdetails: [cDetails]){
    self.name = name
    self.categoryname = categoryname
    self.customerdetails = customerdetails
}
}
struct cDetails{
var dValue: String = ""

init(dValue: String) {
    self.dValue = dValue

}
}
```

In `numberOfRowsInSection` if categoryname is Mobile i need extra row in tableview and in cellForRowAtindexPath i need its text cell?.searchTextfield.text = "Amount" 
like below how to do that?

```
if section == 0 {
    if categoryname == "Mobile"{

     //here i need extra row with cell?.searchTextfield.text = "Amount"
    }
     else
      {
        return selectedDetail?.customerdetails.count ?? 0
      }
    }
```

below is code for present view controller, please help me in the below code.

```
class NewSearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var cell : DetailTableViewCell?

var selectedDetail: JsonData?


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return selectedDetail?.customerdetails.count ?? 0
    }
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textfieldCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell
        cell?.searchTextfield.delegate = self

        if let value = selectedDetail?.customerdetails[indexPath.row] {
            cell?.searchTextfield.text = value.dValue
        } else {
            cell?.searchTextfield.text = "missing data"
        }

    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "buttonCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell
    }
    return cell!
}
}
```

Please help me in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   if section == 0 {
   if categoryname == "Mobile"{

    return selectedDetail?.customerdetails.count + 1 ?? 0
   }
   else
   {
      return selectedDetail?.customerdetails.count ?? 0
   }
  }
 }
```

then

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if indexPath.section == 0 {

    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textfieldCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell
    cell?.searchTextfield.delegate = self
    //play with this validation
    if selectedDetail?.customerdetails.count - 2 >= indexPath.row
    {
    if let value = selectedDetail?.customerdetails[indexPath.row] {
        cell?.searchTextfield.text = value.dValue
    } else {
        cell?.searchTextfield.text = "missing data"
    }
    }
    else
    {
       cell?.searchTextfield.text = "Amount"
    }

} else if indexPath.section == 1 {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "buttonCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell
  }
 return cell!
}
```

Comment: please help in the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59019652/unable-to-validate-added-row-tableview-textfield-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment104285789_59019652

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i can't add a comment so i will respond with this answer.

For what i can see, you're returning 2 in `func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView)`.

I think you need to find a way to program this dynamically. For example, if you store all the data you need in an array. you can simply return `arrayName.count`

So i think you need to write a function to store all the data you need in an array. and return this in your TableView.

I hope i understood your problem well, and this answer made sense.