# Unable to validate added row tableview textField in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, if-statement, uitextfield

For all categories i am getting one value from json but For one category i need extra row in tableview, i have added extra row and text in textfield but i am unable to validate its textfield text value.

this code:

```
  var finalSearchValue : String = ""
  var finalSearchValueAmnt : String = ""
  var cell : BillerTableViewCell?
```

added extra row for `bcategoryname == "Mobile Postpaid"`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

if section == 0 {

    self.rowCount = selectedBiller?.bcustomerparms.count ?? 0
    if selectedBiller?.bcategoryname == "Mobile Postpaid"{

        return  self.rowCount! + 1
    }
    else{
        return selectedBiller?.bcustomerparms.count ?? 0
    }
}
return 1
}
```

**for all categories i am getting mobile number from json to textfield  but for extra row i have added amount textfield**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if indexPath.section == 0 {

    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textfieldCell", for: indexPath) as? BillerTableViewCell
    cell?.searchTextfield.delegate = self

    if self.rowCount! - 1 >= indexPath.row
    {
        if let customerDetail = selectedBiller?.bcustomerparms[indexPath.row] {

            alertParam = customerDetail.paramName
            cell?.searchTextfield.text = alertParam
            if var priceOfProduct: String = customerDetail.minLength {
                alertMinL = Int(priceOfProduct)
            }
            if var priceOfProduct: String = customerDetail.maxLength {
                alertMaxL = Int(priceOfProduct)
            }
            cell?.searchTextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchPhoneEditingChanged(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
        }
        else{
            print("no tf")
            cell?.searchTextfield.text = "missing"
        }
    }
    else{
        cell?.searchTextfield.text = "Amount"
        cell?.searchTextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchAmountEditingChanged(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)

    }
}
return cell!
}
```

here getting both textfield finalvalues

```
@objc func searchPhoneEditingChanged(textField: UITextField) {
finalSearchValue = textField.text!
self.textCount = self.finalSearchValue.count
}

@objc func searchAmountEditingChanged(textField: UITextField) {
finalSearchValueAmnt = textField.text!
}
```

in this is button action:

**if there is no extra row then also it says please enter amount alert, if there no added row then i dont need enter amount alert, i want enter amount alert only if there is added row**

```
  @objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    //let buttonRow = sender.tag
    print("in newbiller search button")
    print("the amount value \(finalSearchValueAmnt)")
    print("the phone value \(finalSearchValue)")

    if self.finalSearchValue.isEmpty{
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter \(self.alertParam!)", in: self)
    }
    else if self.textCount ?? 0 < self.alertMinL ?? 0{
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "\(self.alertParam!) not lessthen \(self.alertMinL!)", in: self)
    }
    else if self.textCount ?? 0 > self.alertMaxL ?? 0{
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "\(self.alertParam!) not graterthen \(self.alertMaxL!)", in: self)
    }
    if self.finalSearchValueAmnt.isEmpty{
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter Amount", in: self)
    }
    else{
    billerFetchService()
    }
}
```

please help me in the above code, to validate added row textfield.

Comment: please tell us what happens and what you want to happen so that we can help you better

Comment: What is the reason for using a TableView here? I get the feeling, that you might be better off with a ScrollView and VerticalStackView?

Comment: @Chris, i have edited question, please help in the code

Comment: @Maverick2805, i am new to ios, i dont know the concept of vertical verticalstackview, i have edited the question, please help me in the code

Comment: i am sorry, i still have no clue what you want and what happened. I was expecting something like : i hoped swift would call function xy but it is never called...but you just write about validating...who is validating what and where?

Comment: @Chris, yes, in `buttonClicked ` if there is only one text field and i enter text in that textfield then also it says  `Please enter Amount`, if there if one textfield the i dont need please enter amout stuff

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the question you posted this morning, and still exhibits the same issues and confusion as on that post.  As you say yourself, you are new and don't understand some of fundamental principles of iOS development.  I think you'd be better spending your time doing a few tutorials than copy and pasting code snippets others write for you.  Longer term you'd get far better value for the time spent.  Apologies if this sounds harsh, but it is well-intended.

Comment: I am not trying to be a pain here, but why did you select a table view to achieve what you are trying to? I am asking because using tableView when you could have this achieved easily another way is just generating more issues for you. So far I understood that you have different amounts of Textfields, depending on Customer Parameters. And those Textfields you need validating? How many fields could there be to validate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the variable `finalSearchValueAmnt` to `""` so it doesn't matter if the user didn't add a value in the text field or that row, where you add the text field is existing or not.

*The below might solve your problem, but you should still consider your approach for your application's view*

Add a variable `var hasFinalSearchValueAmnt : Bool = false`

in `cellForRowAt` set this variable to `true` if this Textfield is shown.

Then in your check function, only show the alert if the Textfield was added and is empty:

```
if self.finalSearchValueAmnt.isEmpty && hasFinalSearchValueAmnt {
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter Amount", in: self)
    }
```

I didn't try this out in Xcode, as there are still missing too many information from your side, how your view should be working.
Also, will only work if there are not other rows added dynamically.

Comment: you are correct, i have different Customer Parameters.. according to paramName i need to show row count in tableview.

Comment: @SwiftIos I still think, that you should layout your view differently as with a tableView. Maybe have a look at some StackView Tutorials (including working with StackViews programmatically)